Why match_bool_prefix with a query with trailing space will generate different results
I tries search the answer for this, but most of the articles say it we use a standard analyzer, it will trim the trailing space, it should generate the same results.
The index mapping:
"orgName": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                }

Part of my query like this :
{
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "match_bool_prefix": {
                  "orgName": {
                    "query": "island",
                    "operator": "AND",
                    "prefix_length": 0,
                    "max_expansions": 50,
                    "fuzzy_transpositions": true,
                    "boost": 1.0,
                  }
                }
              }
            ],
            "adjust_pure_negative": true,
            "boost": 1.0
          }
        }

But if I change the query to "island " with a trailing space, it will generate different results, specifically it calculate the score in different ways.
For the query without trailing space, the score is calculated as :
"value" : 1.0
"description": "orgName:island*",
"details": []

But for the query with trailing space, it is calculated as this:
   "value": 10.185921,

                            "description": "weight(orgName:island in 45462) [PerFieldSimilarity], result of:",

                            "details": [

                                {

                                    "value": 10.185921,

                                    "description": "score(freq=2.0), computed as boost * idf * tf from:",

                                    "details": [

                                        {

                                            "value": 2.2,

                                            "description": "boost",

                                            "details": []

                                        },

                                        {

                                            "value": 6.9498363,

                                            "description": "idf, computed as log(1 + (N - n + 0.5) / (n + 0.5)) from:",

                                            "details": [

                                                {

                                                    "value": 23,

                                                    "description": "n, number of documents containing term",

                                                    "details": []

                                                },

                                                {

                                                    "value": 24509,

                                                    "description": "N, total number of documents with field",

                                                    "details": []

                                                }

                                            ]

                                        },

                                        {

                                            "value": 0.6661975,

                                            "description": "tf, computed as freq / (freq + k1 * (1 - b + b * dl / avgdl)) from:",

                                            "details": [

                                                {

                                                    "value": 2.0,

                                                    "description": "freq, occurrences of term within document",

                                                    "details": []

                                                },

                                                {

                                                    "value": 1.2,

                                                    "description": "k1, term saturation parameter",

                                                    "details": []

                                                },

                                                {

                                                    "value": 0.75,

                                                    "description": "b, length normalization parameter",

                                                    "details": []

                                                },

                                                {

                                                    "value": 4.0,

                                                    "description": "dl, length of field",

                                                    "details": []

                                                },

                                                {

                                                    "value": 5.127382,

                                                    "description": "avgdl, average length of field",

                                                    "details": []

                                                }

                                            ]

                                        }

                                    ]

                                }

                            ]


The simplest way to see which query is generated is by using validate query command:
POST test/_validate/query?explain=true
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match_bool_prefix": {
            "orgName": {
              "query": "island",
              "operator": "AND",
              "prefix_length": 0,
              "max_expansions": 50,
              "fuzzy_transpositions": true,
              "boost": 1
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "adjust_pure_negative": true,
      "boost": 1
    }
  }
}

As you can see island will generate a prefix query while island  will generate an exact match. It happens because when the parser encounters a space  it assumes that this is the end of the token and doesn't process it as prefix.
You never asked an actual question in your question, so I can only explain you what you described. I hope that helps.

Thanks for the answer, but will the analyzer trim the trailing space? I understand that for match_bool_prefix, we will treat the N -1 token as a term match and only the last one as a prefix match, so if the analyzer doesn't trim the query, it will generate a term query for island. But if the analyzer trim the trailing space, it will generate a prefix query for island.

The token produced by analyzer doesn't contain the trailing space and the logic that builds the query checks if the end of the token matches the end of the query, which it doesn't since there is still space at the end. As the result a normal term query instead of prefix query is generated. You can see the logic here: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/55101cf55e945f29a1853fee93acb22b12b876a1/server/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/index/search/MatchQueryParser.java#L523 The lastOffset == offsetAtt.endOffset() is the expression that checks if end of token finishes the query.

Got it, so we need to trim the query manually to solve this problem? Should elastic search trim the query before parse the query?

I think we need to better define "this problem." Could you please explain what you are trying to achieve? That way, I can suggest a better query or an alternative solution. From what I understood so far, it is an expectation problem - Elasticsearch is working correctly, just not as you expect. The match_bool_prefix query was added to support "search-as-you-type" https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/35600. In this mode, until you press space, terms like "islands" and "islanders" are still possible matches. However, once you press space - only "island" can be considered.

From a customer's perspective, he only types in a space, but the search results change, which may be confusing.

Typing space means that the last word is over. It is no longer a prefix. I think the opposite behavior would be confusing.
